# Is it possible to retrieve the second dimension length of a 2 dimension array, if the first dimension is 0-length?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Well, that might be a strange question, and maybe just because I'm not familiar enough with Java.

So, I declared a 2D int array:

```
int[][] arr = new int[0][10]
```

Now, as you can see, the second dimension's length is 10, while the first dimension's length is 0. I'm not sure how Java treats these kind of arrays, but the compiler doesn't produce any errors, which means it's a legit declaration.

Well, I passed the array to some function, and I want to retrieve from within the function, the length of the second dimension.
Of course something like:

```
arr[0].length
```

won't work. is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to use a zero length aray? Why?

Comment: I use arrays to represent rectangles in a coordinate system. for that matter, a 0 length means a rectangle without height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects created by `new int[0][10]` and `new int[0][20]` are equivalent. There *is* no logical "second dimension" here. Effectively you're running something like this:

```
int[][] createArray(int d1, int d2) {
    int[][] ret = new int[d1][];
    for (int i = 0; i < d1; i++) {
        ret[i] = new int[d2];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now if you translate that into your scenario, you'll end up with code which *never reads `d2`*.

If you want to represent a general-purpose *rectangular* array (instead of an array of arrays) you might want to consider creating your own type for it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know java treats them the same. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java, and most every other programming language, are zero-based.  Consider this 2D array:

```
int[][] arr = new int[1][10];
```

This means that there is one row and ten columns in it.

Now, consider this array:

```
int[][] arr = new int[0][10];
```

This means that there are zero rows and (an irrelevant amount of columns) in it.

If you try to index into the second array, you'll find that you can't - an array of length zero has no starting point.

The compiler sees it as valid because you declared dimensions with it, but you won't be able to actually use it in any meaningful way in Java.

Comment: Well, if I knew the length of both dimension, I could use it to compare it to other lengths I use in my program. as I mentioned in a comment, the arrays represent rectangles, so for me, 0 length in one of the dimension is legit and very useable. Thanks!

Comment: @RB14: I think that, instead of using an array in that manner, you would be better served creating your own custom `Rectangle` type which supports a length of zero.  Arrays aren't made to serve that purpose.

Comment: I know the alternatives, but arrays best suit for my needs. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as the length of the second dimension. Consider:

```
int[][] arr = new int[10][10];
arr[5] = new int[42];
```

What is the length of the second dimension? 10 or 42?

No. It doesnt work this way. `arr` is an array with ten elements, each of which must be a reference of an int array (or null). That's all there is to say.